# Upgrading Python

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

According to [the official Python website](https://www.python.org/), the current version of Python 2 is `2.7.10`.

On my computer, I have `2.7.6`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

I figured I'd update to `2.7.10` using `apt-get`.  However, this doesn't work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.7 is already the newest version.
```

`apt-get` is telling me that I already have the newest version.

What gives?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you run?

Comment: Whatever you do, do not delete or modify the default python. The system relies on that version to do many things. Or you may have to totally reinstall if you remove python.

Comment: @EliahKagan that question is newer than this one . . . *sigh*

Comment: Reviewers: [See comments on the other question discussing whether closing this one is appropriate.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725171/update-python-2-7-to-latest-version-of-2-x?noredirect=1#comment1569274_725171)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python package isn't constantly updated in Ubuntu like other applications such as `firefox` or `chromium-browser`. This isn't to say that the package will not get security updates; but I imagine that there probably aren't any major security issues if 14.04 LTS is still running 2.7.6 vs 2.7.10.

If you run `apt-cache showpkg python2.7` or `apt-get changelog python2.7` you can get more info.

Basically, you'll need to source install python (which is pretty easy). I did also find the following PPA: `ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes` but I cannot vouch for it.