# Update Python 2.7 to latest version of 2.x

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python, repository

The version of python2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine is Python 2.7.6. How can I upgrade it to the the latest version of Python 2.X? The latest is currently 2.7.11.

I have tried `apt-get update`/`upgrade`, but the repository doesn't seem to have the latest version.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the answer to the linked question is obsolete while this one is up to date (as far as I can tell). They should either be merged or the duplicate relationship should be reversed.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Done. We can vote to close [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682723/upgrading-python) as a duplicate of this one now, which I've done.

Comment: @dbliss This is [normal practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha) on stackexhange.

Comment: I've removed some of my comments so any future comments will more likely be seen, and to reduce distraction from the actual Q&A here. Anyone interested may read them, in context and with continued discussion, in [***this chat room***](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68889/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-dbliss) ([transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/68889)). I reiterate, however, that any serious concerns are better discussed--and far more likely to be resolved--on [meta] than in comments or chat.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Ubuntu 18.04 and newer:

The new version of Ubuntu no longer uses python 2, so you need to install it with:

```
sudo apt install python-minimal
```

## Ubuntu 17.04 and older:

The answer appears to be to add a third party repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-2.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7
python --version
```

Comment: ```Error: 'fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7' invalid```

Comment: It should be ```sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7``` (you've missed ```ppa:```).

Comment: Thanks. But it works till python 2.7.12, now the latest release is 2.7.13.

Comment: **Important** The mentioned repository won't receive any further updates.

Comment: It appears this PPA has now been taken offline, https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7 403

Comment: You can use it now from https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa but it doesn't support 2.7 releases

Comment: seems that `jonathonf/python-2.7` doesn't carry the packages for bionic

Comment: @Gaia, Try `sudo apt install python-minimal`, it looks like the new way to do it. I has a newer version of python 2.7 than `ppa:jonathonf/python-2.7` too.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Just did as the answer says for my version (17.04 and older) and I just got Python 2.7.14 which is newest version of python 2 today (15.8.2018.). Thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer working as of May 2020

Comment: @MosheZvi What version of Ubuntu are you using?