# Recovering from badly damaged package system (dpkg+python+???)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python, dpkg

Some preamble things usually asked...

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64)
Python2: /usr/bin/python -V -> Python 2.7.12
Python2default: which python -> /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python -V -> Python 2.7.12
dpkg: dpkg --version -> Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
apt: sudo apt --version -> apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Apr 12 2018 10:14:36
c: gcc --version -> gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8~14.04.2) 4.8.5
llvm: clang --version -> clang version 3.9.1-4ubuntu3~14.04.3 (tags/RELEASE_391/rc2)
```

So far so good. The theory of possible causes:

- updated C build system (noticed some c upgrades in recent ubunty's update, expected to see c v5 here but it is possibly pending to install)
- installed llvm update to most recent (for other purposes, but could be influential, even though that llvm is at ver 6 latest llvm for 14 is still 3.9.x)
- tried to update /usr/local python to version 2.7.15 by building it (i noticed that this tends to recompile python modules, looks to me that 2.7.15 py update is somewhat more ambitious and may broke things previously installed)

I am not sure which of this caused an issue, and it could have been me doing something wrong at some point. I have tried a lot of things (researched a lot of similar issues) to fix my issue and recover the package system.

On the way I learned that Ubuntu is so reliant on Python that this is staggering. And I dream of possible ways out of that:

- have special installation of some minimal Python just for system (package) use. Problem here is that from the user side system python is vulnerable as soon as user wants to move to some higher version of python he can mess a lot in system functioning. Even having it alternative (/usr/local/bin) poses a high risk that user will mess with the default installation by mistake.
- have packaging system based on compiled binaries and perhaps some external script and not using python scripts to do the works. Like in my case broken python stops me of installing (or fixing presumably and likely broken) dpkg (and probably some system libs)
- have alternative packaging system that works using different tool so it is possible to reinstall correct package by using alternative packaging installer
- have audit system (something that would tell user what may be broken - for example: package pacx.x expects xxx files to be in yyy place. If something does not match (because user installed something else to use something x-else and messed the libraries).
- have 0 installation recovery minimum system - something that user can install thru unix tools to reach the point to run some packaging system smoothly until more elaborated or major system is back in place.

OK. enough theory!

Step 1: trying to fix if anything is broken in dependences:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-distlib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-distlib
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,120 kB of archives.
After this operation, 559 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: error processing package dpkg (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dpkg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Step2 : Suggested recovering of dpkg.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dpkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dpkg is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python-distlib but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-dev-all (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Step 3: Repeat step 1 - and we get the same result

Step 4: Try to reinstall by force dpkg

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python-distlib but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-dev-all (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Step5: OK OK this pesky python-distlib has to be installed first...

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-distlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-distlib
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,120 kB of archives.
After this operation, 559 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package dpkg (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dpkg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Step 6: now I am in very bad shape. Suggested is (re)installation of dpkg system which I tried in steps 2,3 and 4 (with frustrating outcome)

What can I do now?

I tried hacking into /var/lib/dpkg/status, I have tried to re-create repository list /etc/apt, I have tried to make alternative installation of Python 12, 14 and 15 by compiling from official python source (none helped so I left it at 12).

I know for fact that there is more broken packages that need to be fixed (not listed in examples). In one moment system was so broken that I lost graphical environment and had to work from the terminals (luckily for us that lin-unix is not that dependent on graphics as windows or osx). I had to reinstall unity-desktop so I am at least back to graphical mode (broken python was so influential that even dependence of graphical ui in ubuntu is easily knocked off by it or at least unity one)

I know that last resort would be to install same or newer version of Ubuntu from CD (either 14.04 or ubuntu 16). I would rather stay at 14 because I want to finish some tests and it works fine for me on this particular hardware.

Finally - the question:

What else I could possibly try to recover package system to reasonably functional state in terms of having some alternative package installation system or by fetching/downloading some packages and eventually manually compile and/or install them.

I need to fix:

- python default/system installation (in whatever stable state that was even if that means degrading the version - afaik I remember that original python at the time of installation was 2.7.6 (now completely disappeared)
- dpkg

For posterity this is july 2018.

All hints are welcome, I can hardly make things worse than they currently are - so be bold with ideas ;)

---

Edit 1:

I discovered ppa jonathoff likely related to [Update Python 2.7 to latest version of 2.x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725171/update-python-2-7-to-latest-version-of-2-x)

it could be that I get 2.7.12 from ppa repo automatically. I do not recall when I have added this ppa to my list of repos, but I remember using this recipe.

Currently I am trying to establish as to why I cannot get hold of `python27` package files.

---

Edit 2:

Okay. This is currently my working theory:

I have added https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf ppa to my list. Over time it had moved system python from 2.6 to 2.7. Up to py 2.7.12 things were ok. Once python27 moved to be 2.7.14 things got broken.

I would notice that python version moved, but I thought this was normal ubuntu upgrade.

Now, if you explore Jon's project you will find that current python2.7 is in fact 2.7.14 (and very likely according to his page geared towards ubuntu 16. see https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-2.7) this version if python27 is the one that is not working for me.

I think I tried to fix the problem by installing 2.7.12 myself by building it from sources, but that version as good as it is on its own, it is made for user/programming and it is not the same as ubuntu version of system python (there are subtle differences here that I have read elsewhere but I hoped this would work. It did not. It was bad choice, albeit desperate times require desperate measures).

In original ubuntu archives system python for Ubuntu14 is likely still expected to be 2.7.6 hence even if I try to find python27 in ubuntu release archives chances are I would not find it. (Please someone prove me wrong on this and tell me where I can get python27 in different revisions)

Now question is where I can find this ppa's previous archive and try to revive python to working version.

Last version that worked fine with apt for me was 2.7.12.

The problem is now where to get that particular archive? If it is not lost in time.

Comment: Since you broke dpkg, your easiest way forward is to back up your data and reinstall. DO NOT change the system provided python; you learned that your system depends upon it. You can install other releases of Python alongside (not replacing), but that's a different question.

Comment: I know that this is last resort option. Just hoped I could somehow force one or another installation on top of existing code and clean-up the situation (seen some dpkg hacks). The problem is that I am afraid to come to the same situation after re-installation, since this happened during other normal updates and installations. Very likely I will hold and not install python 2.7.15 as thing started going downhill after that installation (it was not replacement of system one /usr/bin but alternative installation /usr/local/bin but somehow system python stopped working with that).

Comment: Yeah, that 'somehow' is mighty important. Try to avoid doing that next time. Pinning and holding probably won't help, since it's pretty likely that you (not apt) 'somehow' overwrote a key symlink or file. Suggestion: Install 16.04 or 18.04 and Anaconda to play with different version of Python.

Comment: i did try to influence usage of python, in fact it is typical (according to many recipes found around) to alias python to /usr/local/bin  to be users default python. In later attempts to recover system python I tried to do some hacks but this did not work as expected so python27 re-installation seemed as obvious choice. But things there got awry. It was already broken. Guilty as charged :) but, I guess, for a good cause.

Comment: Also to my surprise `sudo which python` also pointed to /usr/local/bin/python I am not really sure where this comes from. Tried to find what could cause this, because i would guess sudo will not autoexecute ~/.bashrc from my user (or I am wrong in some basic understanding)

Comment: third thing is about installation 2.7.15. I did not rewrite links, i  followed python build from source recipe, so this was not a hack, it worked with previous 2.7.12 then later with 2.7.14. the 'somehow' could be buried somewhere in ./configure options. And as far as I could see after researching around, I am not only one that hit problems after python 2.7.15 installation. This is not blame war. I am just trying to understand what to do and what not to do after I am faced again with same or similar problem. Bottom line - ubuntu dependence on specific installation of python scares me.

Comment: Added couple of edits. Investigation pointed to something completely unexpected (to me) - see edit1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to repair `dpkg` manually (download and extract it to the file system):

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb

ar x dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
sudo tar -xvf data.tar.gz -C /
```

Then reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg --reinstall
```

Remove your local Python with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python*
```

Remove python-related PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/python-2.7
```

install normal python from repository

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython-stdlib python-minimal python2.7 \
python-apt python-distlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib
```

and fix the whole system:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

On the final stage check your system consistency with `apt-get` and `debsums`:

```
sudo apt-get check
# debsums
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo debsums_init
sudo debsums --changed --silent
# afterwards reinstall listed packages with
# sudo apt-get install --reinstall package-name
```

Comment: almost there... excellent hints on python removal + critical list of python packages - thank you! dpkg from .deb worked well. Now, I feel dpkg binary shall be good enough. Problem is that reinstalling dpkg still complains about not finishing installation of  python components (see step 4). 1. Do you have recipe to recover python from .deb (in the same fashion as dpkg - not thru apt/dpkg) ? I kind of feel if I fix python+dependent python libs, things will start singing. 2. Do you think that intervention into /var/lib/dpkg/status could help at least passing dpkg re-installation step?

Comment: 3. Python step in your recipe causes on my system `E: Internal Error, No file name for python2.7:amd64` it could be that I am hitting wrong repos. Two interesting things happen here: `Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main python-apt amd64 0.9.3.5ubuntu2 [141 kB]` and `Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpython-stdlib amd64 2.7.10-0ubuntu1 [7,682 B]
Fetched 148 kB in 0s (448 kB/s)` Perhaps I shall look into /etc/apt or somehow cleanup list of source repos. Looks like it attempts going back to 2.7.10 (which is fine for me)

Comment: @user309383 See update above about removing PPA. And please add output of `grep -r ^deb.*ppa /etc/apt/*.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to the question.

Comment: @Norbert I severely cut down apt/deb sources (to only ones of ubuntu system) because your answer has inspired me to go down the line and explore what can be downloaded and from where. I will however include lists for the reference (ones I have). Also, kindly read  edits  (in the question) I made these after your response and subsequent investigation into a problem of finding appropriate python27 archive. Thank you again for the support.

Comment: repo list: https://gist.github.com/ljgww/0c3c76f939ea6367306a251871427419#file-repo-list-norbert-txt

Comment: attempted installations: https://gist.github.com/ljgww/208e9f2f0e45f5021b4d364c028f37e9

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and check package availability with  `apt-cache policy python-minimal libpython-stdlib python2.7 libpython2.7-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal dpkg python-debian python-distlib`.

Comment: N0rbert good news. I managed to fix it (with paying the price of course) but I have working system now (or I believe so). When I put the notes together and test couple of things more I believe I can close this chapter. It was enlightening journey (that did not come to very end as yet :) ) Will write what has made tipping point.

Answer (score 2):

I am providing an answer here not because N0rberts answer was bad. On the contrary, N0rberts answer was 1. inspirative and 2. very useful to me, hence I will accept is as an answer to a question because essentially it is that. Thank you N0rbert for support and patience.

My answer here is to shed a light on some side effects and edge cases.

I could do this in question but I am of opinion that question shall remain as question and answer is different thing. Since there is a lot of ground to cover and I have to dig some examples from my logs, this answer until it is complete will be edited several times until I come to the point of what has happened and how I overcome obstacles.

## Review of what has happened

That I have learned on the journey of fixing...

1. In one moment I have realized that I cannot install or update anything on my Ubuntu14 (it could easily be a newer one)
2. I made a theory of what may be wrong because I was trying to build some new software and things were breaking so I was trying to install various fixes to that build. The things simply started breaking but not breaking critically.

> lesson1: what it turned to be influential to the cause of the problem was coming from different angle, not from the theory I had. I thought that my recent installations of LLVM influenced python while culprit of the problem was PPA repository that I have installed to solve something else. The problem is that PPA in question I installed a while ago (1y+) and forgot that it is there. Silently Ubuntu was updating what's new (even when that is not really recommended). That bad decision of mine will be more elaborated later.
> -- Moral of the lesson: do not theorize what it may be - try to investigate and ponder facts carefully.

3. Tried various recipes until I came in the state of no recovery. In essence I have broken 2 essential things in my Linux: 1. `dpkg` and 2. system `python`.  In one moment whole system broke to the point that I lost graphical environment, first some apps start breaking (this was happening over period of couple of months) and finally at the lowest point I end-up that I could run my Ubuntu only from console terminals (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>). Being on linux for a long time I was originally dwelling on the command line. Of course things are way easier when you have graphics, mainly because you can run browser to research potential solutions. I am programmer and my specie is known to be a bit dogmatic (dogmatic = believe in automation of dogs :) ) this means I will cling to some thought ignoring potential facts.

> lesson2: I am of belief that there are 2 ways of fixing thing when OS is in question. 1. Reinstall the whole thing 2. try to fix. I have tried both in the past. Lately, I am realizing that option 2 has more value. By trying to fix things I learned a lot more about OS. I was to the certain extent ignorant. Now, If I just reinstalled OS I would eventually come to more problematic situation which would eventually instigate clean installation from scratch which means all fine tuning and all sorts of other data will be lost.
> -- Moral of the lesson: Learn, do not take easy way forward, be bold. Ultimately, it is rewarding.

4. I have communicated problem here and talked to real people. Thank you JonathonF for valuable insights into PPA purpose and providing information about archive.

> Lesson3: During investigation I learned that Jonathon does not really recommend his PPA to be used and if you do, do it on your own risk. In fact my Linux is not mission critical - it is my hobby computer (but it is valuable to me as I use it for all sort of things: from online banking via fun to evaluating software or programming languages that I would use professionally.)
> -- Moral of the lesson: if you cannot figure everything yourself - talk to people. There are valuable hints in what they do and what they will tell you. But try to read carefully, especially purpose of PPA's.

## The way to recovery

1. the first thing that made difference was to repair `dpkg`.

The beginning of NOrberts answer addresses that. Download `.deb`, extract files and do manually what all these package tools will do for you automatically.

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg --reinstall
```

vicious circle
did not work for me because `apt` looks to me to be reliant on scripts that are done in `python` and `python` modules did not want to get installed via `apt` (vicious circle). So I could not fix this step until I have fixed `python` first. The claim here that `python` is used is a feeling. In fact at the end I never tried to install/fix `apt` program to make system working - there is something to that. I cannot prove this but it remains strong automated dog to me.

Second part of N0rbert suggests to remove alternative `python`.

I have installed alternative `python` because I needed newer version to try to do something (do not remember exactly what was at the time).

In essence I have had a mess of different pythons installed and not very clear which python is using what. This goes partially to Ubuntu experience and partially to Python experience. Ubuntu runs its own version for the reasons known to them, in some cases this is not of help as documentation may mislead you until you learn the differences. The problem was I did not have an idea how to properly install system python. It comes pre-installed during OS installation and it is recommended to remain unchanged (in spite of facts that this policy may pose some other risk). On the other hand installation procedures generally tend not to talk to the user. Even if I did something wrong by different ways of configuring or installing I would not know. The bottom line, I did not find documentation how to fix system python anywhere. In fact there are plenty of recipes that would tell you to do:

```
sudo apt-get install python27
```

possibly this would fix a problem in normal circumstances, which means you have `python` considerably working well and `apt` is working for you.

first part of a problem with python was that my default python was alternative python. Whatever I did was actually not hitting system python.

Hence another hint from N0rbert was essential - remove any reference to alternative python. Since this python I have installed by compiling python source and installing from that, this python was not part of normal package system. Deleting it directly from the disk was what N0rbert suggested and this is what I did among first things (I could easily recover it if need be).

Some other hints suggested to de-install python. When I tried that it made a long list of items that would de-install. I was not ready for that - there were a lot of applications and other things and I thought - who would reinstall all of this and what it would do. About this a bit later.

Since de-installing system python was out of the question the only possibility was to try to force to install it on top.

I do not know how many different things I tried in order to do this. None of them replaced system python. In one moment I got desperate as python in the best case was 2.7.12 (in place of system python). Original ubuntu 14 distribution is hard fixed to 2.7.6. Which seemed to me too old. I would expect that ubuntu through the normal update will come to some 2.7.9 or 2.7.10 but this is not the case. If you look at ubuntu archives only python that is shown and has packages is called python27 and actually it is python 2.7.6.

This has lead me to the question - how come when I try to install pyton27 I get python 2.7.14 which is failing to install but also when I get version of /usr/bin/python (points to python2 which points to python27 which is binary) I regularly get python 2.7.12.

After some days, sleep thinking etc. I came to conclusion that I do not know where 2.7.12 and attempted 2.7.14 are coming from. In the meantime I was experimenting with installing 2.7.15 as alternative - which was good working and I thought - well perhaps I could do the thing with .15 better than previous versions. And this was a mistake.

Interestingly enough 2.7.12 in `/usr/bin` was quite resilient staying at same version no matter what I did.

This has lead me to suspicion and investigation showed that I had Jonathon's PPA and there in his PPA the most recent python27 is actually 2.7.14. Since 2.7.12 was still working for me with minimal side effects I have sent email to Jonathon to tell me if he has python27 in some earlier incarnation e.g. 2.7.10 (somewhere mentioned in installation) or perhaps 2.7.12 or even some earlier version I can try to install. Jonathon was quite quick to reply and pointed me to his archives (also available online) but in his archives I have found that earliest python27 build is actually 2.7.12 and this is why it was this version that was clinging. In fact Jonathon mentions that he is building currently for Ubuntu 16 and soon he will stop doing that and from the fall of this year will start building for Ubuntu 18. Python27 that was in his archive was not even built for my version of Ubuntu. WOW. I figured I have made bad decision a while a go.

I removed all PPAs from apt list. I even removed default ubuntu list (how bad was that decision will come later)

In one moment I thought I was done. There was no way back machine that would bring me to previous state. And for a while I pondered a lot of things including installing ubuntu16 to super impose with newer set up.

APT was still broken, pending python parts did not want to install.

Then I decided. I will try to install in hack or no hack way original python 2.7.6 as given from ubuntu. It was that or nothing.

But even this proved not to be easy task. Since APT was broken I needed a way to install and I started learning about `dpkg`. Apparently APT is nice front end for DPKG and actually it is `dpkg` that does the hard work.

It would be easier if I had Ubuntu CD where I installed this OS from but this CD is, after several moves I made in past couple of years, god knows where. Darn.

Luckily internet is vast library so help came in the form of a archive site. It was this one that came to be useful: https://pkgs.org/

I guess any package that you would need is there from several distributions including ubuntu.

## Which .deb to download?

This posed as main question. APT was not working also because dependences may be broken. This is something any linux dist could improve - some sort of audit system which will tell you which file from which package is not what it is in original package.

I do not know what archives I need to install and I do not know how to install it but even in worst case since these .deb are archives I would eventually extract them and replace files with originals.

In fact it turned out that this is not really necessary. DPKG can do this job (provided it is recovered to working state considerably, and N0rbert task #1 was ensuring this. It was not ideal but DPKG seem to be binary program so it would work well if data is OK.

I discovered that `dpkg` has option `-i` to install.

So I downloaded `.deb` and:

```
dpkg -i dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

actually went well. `apt` stopped complaining that `dpkg` is not configured well. This was already good wind.

It is worth mentioning that I did not exactly arrive at this point immediately, it was rather trial and error and realization that apt-get is not going to do the clean-up work for me for the installation. I am not sure where Ubuntu keeps meta info about packages (I suspect this is in /var/lib/dpkg/status file) because hacking into statuses of packages did not always render appropriate effect. I am still of belief that some sort of audit tool shall be developed as an aid to compare what is actually in files versus what the records of installation say that is in files.

APT system is modular, one thing may not be working but another may as well be. I learned that I can do:

```
apt-get download python
```

this will get you some version of python, but it may not be what you want. In Ubuntu 14 case above one will fetch you python 2.7.5. (if you have just system defined sources - which is the default)

Also this function makes sense as `apt` downloads stuff before installing. It is just I never saw this and I always see something like `wget site bla bla`. I believe `apt-get download` is safer option. Use it.

```
apt-get download python27
```

will get you some .deb archives to your local disk. I did not need all of them.

Investigation showed that I need the file `/usr/bin/python27` but not just any `/usr/bin/python27` file because my `/usr/bin/python27` was version 2.7.12 and I was determined to bring back original one which is 2.7.6. Now there is about 2000+ packages in Ubuntu that are python and I needed archive that has this file in it. After looking into archives I have realized that there is only one package that holds this file is: python2.7-minimal_2.7.6-8_amd64.deb

So i have installed this with dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.6-8_amd64.deb 

dpkg: warning: downgrading libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 from 2.7.12-1~14.02 to 2.7.6-8
(Reading database ... 1548765 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.6-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.6-8) over (2.7.12-1~14.02) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.6-8) ...
```

Subsequent step was a bit of a shock. I got into a habit of doing `sudo apt-get -f install` almost after every theory or trial command I made in the hope that this will fix the rest. In fact once I have put 2.7.6 in the original place (overwriting later versions) -f install option showed a long list of applications and libraries:

```
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 556 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/354 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,748 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

This was a turning point. I either do this or I go for other option (installing Ubuntu from scratch). Before I have executed this one I took snapshot of all history in my terminal with the idea that even if I remove all these libs and packages that are dependent on later python version, perhaps if I need something of these that will be removed at least I would have a list of names I needed to install.

So I pressed Y.

Cooking took a while. And another problem started emerging with a shy message:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libjack0 jackd1 jackd1-firewire
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
```

Essentially I did not have another option but to install it without verification.

Now, I have mentioned before that it was bad decision to remove all repositories to get software (was determined to switch them one by one). I selected a mirror source site closer to me instead of main Ubuntu site. Perhaps because things have not been properly installed secure keys have got messed up. I will never know what was the main reason for it.

At this point I did not realize how important is this so unauthenticated warning was following me in subsequent commands. But from another side installation was working so I did not find this critical for desperate situation. It was already all or nothing, so as long as it was working

Later on I switched to see if I can run 'Software Updater' with a hope that updater will resolve other dependences. But Software Updater was strict. It refused to install any updates or fixes at least until authentication is not setup properly. I discovered wonderful apt commands such as `sudo apt-key update` and `sudo apt-key list` not that they have been helpful immediately but at some later point they actually did become useful.

Among other interesting ways I find this useful:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
```

Replace last one with key you need. Also there is 'Passwords and Keys' application that I did not find particularly friendly or useful (except to discover some old passwords for various logins)

Eventually this issue become fixed by removing all .gpg files `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. Being bitten before I have moved them somewhere else for backup if I need some of them again.

What was helpful here was:

```
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
sudo launchpad-getkeys
sudo apt-get update
```

launchpad-getkeys is interesting piece of software, simple but effective. First it reads all your missing keys and then it tries to retrieve them. Saves a ton of manual work.

Now I could properly reinstall dpkg and python2.7 by using apt-get.

## The End?

One may think that there is the end of this story. System recovered. Updates working. Software update working. A list of de-installed software with some manipulation and bringing back some ppa's are back in function.

But, it was too early to be proud on achievement in the same time relief was significant.

Not to make this endless story these are few pointers that I have learned by later fixing particular purpose items:

- mod_wsgi was not really working with 2.7.6 (so I longed to have some later version, perhaps this was reason in the first place why I looked for update of system python.
- Flask and Virtualenv have been behaving badly. Discovered that these will have some commands in `/usr/local/bin` so I had to `pip uninstall` followed by removing commands and then reinstalling this properly to system python not by using pip but by using `apt-get install python-flask` ... on a general note `/usr/local/` in relation to python kept appearing in all sort of places. I thought I removed all things python in `/usr/local` but had issues with pip installed python modules, so whenever I hit the issue I first do `pip uninstall` and then install it properly.
- My original feeling that something got wrong when I installed llvm (and updating C compiler) was not without facts. In fact apart from JonathonF's PPA there is another one that makes profound changes to system python and that is: ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa. In fact once I brought that back into the picture suddenly system python got upgraded from 2.7.6 back to 2.7.12. But whole system is now working properly even mod_wsgi and virtualenv. This last one (virtualenv) is essential and I will make sure to use it more when I experiment even if it is by virtualenv-ing a version of python and them try to mess whatever. At least if I mess python I will mess the one in virtualenv ;)

Hi to all tldr; people :)